# How do I retrieve two different conditional sets of data from the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Success Criteria:

- retrieve Employees who started after 2006
- for employees with a sale provide number of days from start date to sale date
- for employees without a sale, provide number of days from start date to current date and emphasize no sale to date

> NOTE there are multiple sales per employee in the actual data set thats why i've used the
> aggregate MIN

What I have so far in code:

```
SELECT
    People.Employee
    MIN(DATEDIFF(DAY,Dates.Startdate,Dates.Salesdate)) as 'Days to First Sale'    
FROM People
LEFT JOIN Dates ON People.ID = Dates.ID
    AND YEAR(CASE WHEN Dates.SalesDate > Dates.DeliveryDate THEN Dates.SalesDate ELSE 
    Sales.DeliveryDate END) > (2006)
```

Current Code Output:

| Employee | Days to First Sale |
| --- | --- |
| Brandi | 33 |
| Mark | 18 |

Table #1 "People"

| ID | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| 301 | John |
| 557 | Brandi |
| 221 | Sheila |
| 489 | Mark |

Table #2 "Dates"

| ID | StartDate | SaleDate | DeliveryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 11/24/2005 | 3/1/2006 | 4/1/2006 |
| 557 | 12/3/2007 | 1/6/2008 | 2/1/2008 |
| 221 | 9/7/2006 | NULL | NULL |
| 489 | 8/13/2006 | 9/1/2006 | 10/1/2006 |

Desired Outcome:

| Employee | Days to First Sale |
| --- | --- |
| Brandi | 33 |
| Sheila | 5,475 Days with no sale |
| Mark | 18 |

Comment: What does that code do, and why is that wrong or insufficient? i.e. show current output and explain why it's not as desired.

Comment: why you've used aggregate min() ?  do you have multiple rows per employee in dates table?

Comment: Yes, in actual data set there are multiple rows per employee based on number of sales in dates table...

Answer (score 0):

try this column:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, Dates.StartDate, COALESCE(Dates.SalesDate,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) as VARCHAR) +
case when Dates.salesdate is null then ' no sales' else '' end
```

Comment: thank you for the effort Alex, but what does the "dd" stand for?

Comment: for difference in days you pass dd, for minutes mi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the logic using a `cte` and simply join to get the corresponding names

```
with d as (
    select id, Concat(Min(DateDiff(day,Startdate,IsNull(Salesdate,GetDate()))), Iif(Min(salesdate) is null,' Days with no sale','')) Sales
    from dates
    where startdate>'20060101'
    group by Id
)
select p.Employee, d.sales [Days to First Sale]
from d
join people p on p.Id=d.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you always want to get the StartDate from the Dates table, regardless of the status of the sales date column, you need to simplify your join. Putting some contingent logic on the join using the sales date column, means you are preventing all your dates being returned.

You can put your case statement with more complex logic in your select, as that will not prevent any rows from existing - also, you will need to cast the integer results of your datediff as a varchar if you also want to output a string. You also need to include a group by, you can't just demand a min() without saying what you are aggregating by!

Another point is why is there a left join? It looks as though there should always be at least one row per employee in the Dates table with the Start date - if there isn't, then you have no reliable way of filtering the employees by start date, otherwise the left join is a bit superfluous.

I would do something like:

```
SELECT p.ID,
p.Employee ,
case when min(Dates.Salesdate) IS NOT NULL then 
  cast (DATEDIFF(DAY,min(Dates.Startdate),min(Dates.Salesdate)) as varchar(50))
  else 
  cast (DATEDIFF(DAY,min(Dates.Startdate),getdate()) as varchar(50)) + ' days without sale' 
end as 'Days to First Sale'    
FROM People p
LEFT JOIN Dates d ON p.ID = d.ID
and datepart(year,d.StartDate) >= 2006
group by p.Id, p.Employee
```

Data modelling hint - I would create a seperate column to flag employees without a sale, and just have integers in Days to First Sale -  otherwise by mixing integers and strings, you will not be able to do any calculations with your Days to First Sale column.

Comment: I might have done something wrong BUT this is actually returning me the "Days to first sale" and "days for no sales" combined in one column without being able to distinguish between them

the left join is because in the actual data set one employee can have multiple sales and so multiple sale dates, but the start dates and IDs would remain the same.

Comment: In your desired outcome table, you showed that you wanted both in one column. The else clause adds a phrase "days without sale" to the integer value, as you specified. I am not logged into a sql server right now to check, maybe change the second cast statement to cast as varchar(10) instead of 50.

Comment: The left join is not doing what you think it is. If you have a one to many relationship, then doing an inner join between the two tables will return a row for each record in the "many" table, i.e. your Dates table. A left join would only make sense if there were potentially NO matching rows in your dates table, but if that were the case, you would also not be able to retrieve a start date.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out!